# RecyclerView is blank when I transition to other fragments from navigation.xml

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm using a navigation.xml to transition to other `fragments`. but the problem is that when I transition to other `fragment` and come back. The `RecyclerView` in the `fragment` is blank. I'm using the MVVM stucture + jetpack. to make an app, therefore I'm binding the data to the `RecyclerView`. Is there a way to prevent the `fragment` from going blank ? Some samples or hints would be lovely. I would love to hear from you!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_show">

    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/navigation_show"
            android:name="test.ShowFragment"
            android:label="@string/menu_bar_show"
            tools:layout="@layout/layout_show">
    </fragment>
    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/navigation_help"
            android:name="test.HelpFragment"
            android:label="@string/menu_bar_help"
            tools:layout="@layout/layout_help">
    </fragment>

</navigation>
```

This is in the mainActivity

```
 private fun setupNavigation() {
        val navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.mainNavigationFragment)
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, navController)

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
            val actionBar = supportActionBar
            actionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)
            actionBar.setLogo(null)
            actionBar.title = ""

            when (destination.id) {
                R.id.navigation_show -> {
                    supportActionBar!!.setLogo(R.drawable.pic)
                }
                else -> {
                    actionBar.title = destination.label.toString()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: hey, which fragment method you are using to navigate to other fragments?

Comment: You need to understand the fragment life cycle :). This happens because when you navigate to another fragment the first fragment view gets destroyed but it's state/data is there. All you need to do is save the fragment's state when you move to another one and using onSavedInstanceState() method you can retrieve you data.

Comment: how should I do save it ? I'm using navigation.xml to transition between fragments...Some sample would be helpful.

Comment: @Nancy: Try below step may be this step will solve your problem.

**1.Make sure to add first Base Fragment without addToBackStack() method. Because it is responsible for Navigation Back. We don't want to go back from first Page. So don't add it to backStack.**

**2.While moving from Fragment A to Fragment B if you have call fragmentTransacation.add then while comming back from B to A. onViewCreated or onResume method will not called as you have added a fragment to it. So in order to hit onResume or onViewCreated while going back to Fragment A. you should call fragmentTransaction.replace**

Comment: can you please post your code that would be helpful to identity the issue

Comment: @rafa I added the code, but it's just transitioning with navigation.xml